# Create Django Authentication using Amazon Cognito

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, backend, amazon-cognito

I am trying to run my Django login and signup authentication using Amazon Cognito and all other services using default database.

But I am not able to find any suitable example for that.

I have followed the following documentation. But didn't get any success.

https://github.com/labd/django-cognito-jwt

I am usinng the following libraries:

Django==4.1.7

djangorestframework==3.14.0

django-cognito-jwt==0.0.4

Can anyone please help me in this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/cognito.html

Try out the cognito backend for this library, it has integration with django rest framework out of the box, and takes care of all the user management for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34665623)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).